# Find rows where there are duplicates in another column in the designated group of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the data set `df`, I want to groupby two groups of `foo` and `bar` in column `B`, and identify the duplicated rows that exist in both groups. How can I achieve this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1],
                   'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']})
df = df.sort_values('B')
df
Out[15]: 
   A    B
1  2  bar
3  3  bar
0  1  foo
2  2  foo
4  3  foo
5  1  foo
```

The expected result:

```
   A    B  Indicator
1  2  bar  True  # value 2 also present in foo, so returns True
3  3  bar  True  # value 3 also present in foo, so returns True
0  1  foo  False  # value 1 only present in foo, so returns False
2  2  foo  True  # value 2 also present in bar, so returns True
4  3  foo  True  # value 3 also present in bar, so returns True
5  1  foo  False  # value 1 only present in foo, so returns False
```

**Updates:**

Assuming column `B` has **more than 2 categories**, the sample data `df` is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],  'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'baz']})
df = df.sort_values('B')
df
Out[30]: 
   A    B
1  2  bar
3  3  bar
5  2  baz
6  1  baz
0  1  foo
2  2  foo
4  3  foo
```

In this case, the expected result would be as follows:

```
   A    B  Indicator
1  2  bar  True  # The value 2 occurs in categories baz, bar, and foo, so returns True.
3  3  bar  False  # The value 3 only occurs in categories bar and foo, so returns False.
5  2  baz  True  # The value 2 occurs in categories baz, bar, and foo, so returns True.
6  1  baz  False  # The value 1 only occurs in categories baz and foo, so returns False.
0  1  foo  False  # The value 1 only occurs in categories baz and foo, so returns False.
2  2  foo  True  # The value 2 occurs in categories baz, bar, and foo, so returns True.
4  3  foo  False  # The value 3 only occurs in categories bar and foo, so returns False.
```

Comment: There are only 2 groups?

Comment: Yes, my data currently has only two categories in column B.

Comment: Ok, then working both solutions.

Comment: Well, I'm having a bit of a choice problem. Which one should I choose to accept as the answer for this question? One is more concise and one is more general. Anyway, thanks for sharing your answers.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have multiple groups, you can use:

```
data = {'A': [2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3],
        'B': ['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values('B')

df['Indicator'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique') == df['B'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A    B  Indicator
0  2  bar       True
1  3  bar      False
2  2  baz       True
3  1  baz      False
4  1  foo      False
5  2  foo       True
6  3  foo      False
```

Comment: @ahbon. I updated my answer, can you check it please? It works now for multiple groups.

Comment: Sorry. Typo :) I used `df['A'].nunique()` instead of `df['B'].nunique()`!!! Thanks. The output for your new example should be : `[True, False, False, True, False, True, False]`

Answer (score 1):

If need intersection `B` values per all `A` groups use:

---

First idea is use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for get `A` values if exist in each group and filter `A` values in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B).astype(bool)

df['Indicator'] = df['A'].isin(df1.index[df1.all(axis=1)])
print(df)
   A    B  Indicator
1  2  bar       True
3  3  bar       True
0  1  foo      False
2  2  foo       True
4  3  foo       True
5  1  foo      False
```

Or use intersection of sets per groups by `B` for last `DataFrame` in question:

```
setlist = df.groupby('B')['A'].agg(set)
print (setlist)
B
bar       {2, 3}
baz       {1, 2}
foo    {1, 2, 3}
Name: A, dtype: object

u = set.intersection(*setlist)
print (u)
{2}

df['Indicator'] = df['A'].isin(u)
print (df)
   A    B  Indicator
1  2  bar       True
3  3  bar      False
5  2  baz       True
6  1  baz      False
0  1  foo      False
2  2  foo       True
4  3  foo      False
5  1  foo      False
```

Comment: I tested your methods and both gave the same correct result. Thanks.